# How to split a word in a string and replace letters with different characters in JS

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'm trying to make a function which takes a random word and then splits the word into individual letters, then replace the letters with different characters to hide the word.

This is what I thought of originally, but does not work at all (selectWord and answer are both declared outside of all functions):

```
function word() {
selectWord = answer.split('').map(letter , " _ ").join('');

document.getElementById('correct-word').innerHTML = selectWord;}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `.map(letter , " _ ")` ???  Try `.map(letter => " _ ")`

Comment: or even just `.map(() => " _ ")` since `letter` is not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function word() {
    selectWord = answer.split('').map(() => " _ ")).join('');
    
    document.getElementById('correct-word').innerHTML = selectWord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map takes a function.

```js
selectWord = answer.split('').map(letter=> " _ ").join('');
```